# Parent components show over child form

Tags: delphi, parent-child

I've been following the below page in order to have a child Form that I can click on its components (such as an edit) and have proper focus:

[Working with MDI Forms in Delphi](https://soonsantos.medium.com/working-with-mdi-forms-in-delphi-d7c37a176f5f)

The problem now is that the components on the parent Form show on top of the child Form. If I use the `SendToBack()` command for those components, they completely disappear. Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have a Form with buttons and a ListView that displays client info. When I click on a client, I can click a button to view or edit that client, alternatively add a new one. The Edit/Add pops up a Form where I can input the info and save it. I'm using an `OnClick` event for each Edit that has a `SetFocus()`. That gets focus on each Edit, but then all the text is selected, so I cannot click on the line and start editing text - it just overrides unless I use an arrow first.

Initially, I used regular Forms and that's where I had the focus issue. MDI fixed that, but now it's the parent components that show on top of the child.

Comment: That is how MDI works. The main form is not supposed to have anything else than a menu bar and optionally a toolbar, aligned `alTop`. The child forms use the rest of the space.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg ok, that makes sense. Maybe you can point me in the correct direction (and if what I want to do is possible).
I have a form with buttons and a ListView that displays client info. When you click on a client, you can click a button to view or edit that client, alternatively add a new one. The Edit/Add pops up a form where you can input the info and save it. I'm using an OnClick for each edit that has a SetFocus. That gets focus on each edit, but then all the text is selected, so I cannot click on the line and start editing text - it just overrides unless I use an arro first.

Comment: Please don't expand on your question here in comments, but click the `Edit` button beneath the tags of your question to edit it. MDI is not really suitable for your case, better use ordinary secondary forms for editing client data.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg thanks, I did that. I initially did use regular forms and that's where I had the focus issue. MDI fixed that, but now it's the parent components that show on top of the child.

Comment: @WackyWabbit I would suggest placing a `TPanel` on the MainForm, and set its `Align` as desired.  Then, you can put your extra MainForm controls in that Panel. Leave the rest of the MainForm's client area for MDI child Forms only.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning MDI forms: that is how MDI works. The main form is not supposed to have anything else than a menu bar and optionally a toolbar, aligned `alTop`. The child forms use the rest of the space. Well as @RemyLebeau suggested, you can add other controls too, if you align them.

But it turned out that the actual problem with using ordinary secondary forms was that the text in an edit control on the secondary form becomes selected when you set focus to the edit control in a button click. That is easy to change, right after you set the focus to an edit control:

```
Edit2.SelLength := 0; // nothing selected, cursor at beginning

Edit3.SelStart := Length(Edit3.Text); // nothing selected, cursor at end of text
```

Comment: that gets me pretty close to where I need to be. I posted another guestion regarding positions since that is not directly related to this. You did answer my main question here though.